# Database design to see transactions made to each value

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am creating some financial software. In such software it is essential not only to know the current value of fields, but also to know what the value of the field was earlier, who made the change and when, so one can go back in history to for example see who committed a crime.

My question is what the best practice for creating such a design is? The DBMS I use is PostgreSQL. Of course it will be the current values of each field that are accessed mostly. Also, only changes to values need to get recorded so making snapshot backups does not seem like the appropriate way to do this.

I tried searching for "journaling" and "transaction history", but came up without results.

Comment: All the good designs keep transaction table separate...A transaction table is exactly what it sounds like.. I am not sure what are your fields but in that table, each line represents one transaction.. i.e. a deposit, a withdrawal or a transfer

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel It sound like that would be one huge table, which would make it a very expensive query to see what the history of one specific table cell was.

Comment: Of course it will be big. You can archive old data according to your needs and performance. You can further keep a flash table that stores short term data and a full table to keep all the data till last archive point. But that would create a slight more work because you are storing same data twice (double risk of data corruption). With indexes and efficient queries, you should be alright. Again, I am not sure your data load so I cant speculate much.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler describes the design of financial transaction systems in his book "Analysis Patterns" - this is about OO design more than database design, but worth reading.

The traditional way is to create a table representing a "ledger", along the following lines:

```
transactionID | AccountID | TransactionDate | TransactionValue | OtherData...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The balance at any point in time is the sum of the "TransactionValue" up to that date.

It's true that such tables tend to grow very large - but databases like Postgres are very effective at managing large datasets. In practice, you can easily manage tens or hundreds of millions of records on modern hardware, as long as you can rely on a good indexing scheme.

If you do run into a performance limit, the common solution is to create summary entries - so you move all records up to a certain date into an archive table, and insert a summary record for that date. Depending on your data volumes, you might do this by decade, year, month, or even week.